# XNA mouse position in windows forms

Tags: c#, xna-4.0, input, windows-forms

I am using this code in Update method in XNA RenderControl in Windows Forms:

```
...
Mouse.WindowHandle = renderControl1.Handle;
MouseState stat=Mouse.GetState();
...
```

Everything works fine but when I want to record it with Fraps I get this result: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oDmzAIx_wU0 mouse position is moved but in screen everything is OK. When first line is removed I have moved cursor on screen but not in video. Is posible to have same result in both cases?

Comment: Can you take a look at my classes? How did you get the mouse to work? My keyboard works, but mouse input isn't updating: http://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/61006/mouse-input-not-updating-in-custom-xna-winforms-panel

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure if it will work in your specific problem but I also use Windows Forms with XNA and after trying many ways to get *consistent* mouse behavior across several different situations, I settled with this:

```cs
public Vector2 GetMousePosition()
{
    System.Drawing.Point point = this.PointToClient(Control.MousePosition);
    return new Vector2(point.X, point.Y);
}
```

This method returns the current mouse position relative to the control bounds. Put that inside your control class and see how it works for you. This solved a few problems I was having when I tried using the XNA Mouse API for reading the mouse position, in particular when placing my XNA rendering control inside of another control.

Your problem seems to be a different one, but I've just tried using Fraps on my application which uses the method described above, and it's working correctly, so I think it should probably solve your problem too.