# Xna winform scaling and mouse position

Tags: xna, c#

I am attempting to create a simple 2d level editor using xna and winforms.

I have used the app hub win form samples as a starting point. At first I was having trouble with the mouse coordinates but after setting the mouse handle to the control,  it is working fine.

But now I want to implement scaling into the editor. I want the level editor to always be 720p. I have accomplished this by rendering to a render target set to 720 and then draw this using sprite batch to the back buffer. This also works great with letter boxing to keep the right ratio. I used the technique detailed here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7591466/xna-resize-window-without-increasing-resolution.

However because of the letting boxing my mouse coordinates are now wrong again. Can someone help work out how to solve this? I tried getting the size of the letter box and subtracting that from the mouse coordinates but that didn't work.

Has anyone got any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This is almost exactly the same method I implemented for my games, and the way I'm solving this problem is by encapsulating both the offset and the scaling in a matrix. I added this method to my resolution independence class:

```
public Matrix GetResolutionMatrix()
{
    float ratio = (float) virtualWidth / physicalWidth;
    return Matrix.CreateTranslation(-area.X, -area.Y, 0) * 
           Matrix.CreateScale(ratio, ratio, 1f);
}
```

And I use that matrix to calculate the mouse position inside my input manager, by doing something like:

```
Vector2.Transform(mousePosition, resolution.GetResolutionMatrix())
```

For comparison here's my complete implementation:

http://pastie.org/4265585

And the relevant portion of the input module:

http://pastie.org/4265592

Also, check [this answer](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/23128/11686) in case you're having trouble getting the correct "raw" mouse position in relation to the xna control.

Comment: This is also the way I do it. In terms of mouse position, I prefer the XNA mouse. As long as you set the window handle `Mouse.WindowHandle = this.Handle;` I've had no problems using it with win forms.

Comment: @Bigfellahull If you're referring to the last link I posted, I also only ran into problems when I started adding the xna control deeper in the control hierarchy, e.g. inside of a panel or another container, instead of being placed directly on the form.

Comment: Really. Even inside other controls, as long as I set the window handle to that of the xna control that extends the graphics device, it *seems* to work fine. But like you mention in the other question, using win forms for mouse input works well too.